# Admin on rest : How to Edit a JSON Array field of Key Value Pairs

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have a data structure in the REST end point like this :

```
[

    {k:"1", v:"ABC"},
    {k:"2", v:"XYZ"},

]
```

How to Display such data in Edit Form such that I can **remove and Add New** ? If I use `SelectArrayInput`, then it complains of :

```
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {k, v}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Can someone please help on what is the best possible way ?